# Rails helper loops html is appearing on my view

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, helper

Hi so i am using a helper module on my view to run some functions...
But somehow this part of the helper code , is appearing on my html..

```
for i in 0..minedTextSize
```

**This is on the html**

[image: This is whats appearing on html]

**This is the html calling the helper method.**

```
<h1>TEST TEST</h1>
<%=extract_value("filePath")%>
```

in my controller i just included the helper method

```
class MainPageController < ApplicationController
  include ExtractHelper

  def index
  end
end
```

any ideas?

UPDATE########

Here is my helper ruby code

```
module ExtractHelper
  require 'rubygems'
  require 'nokogiri'
  require 'open-uri'
  require 'pdf-reader-turtletext'

  def download_pdf(url)
    found = false
    page = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http//www.somesite.com")
    puts page.class   # => Nokogiri::HTML::Documents

    for i in 0..(page.css('a').size - 1)
      if(page.css('a')[i]['href'][-4,4] != ".pdf")
        next
      else
        found = true
        file_link = page.css('a')[i]['href']
        file_link.gsub!(' ','%20')
        link = "http//www.somesite.com/" + file_link # Generate the $
        puts link
        download = open(link)

       IO.copy_stream(download,"/home/ec2user/my_project/pdfFiles/Demo.pdf")
        puts file_link + " has been downloaded."
        @link = file_link + " has been downloaded."
        if found == true
          break
        end
      end  #if
    end     # for
  end    #def


  def extract_value(filePath)
    filePath = "/home/ec2-user/my_project/pdfFiles/Demo.pdf"
    reader = PDF::Reader::Turtletext.new(filePath)

    textangle = reader.bounding_box do
      inclusive true
      page 4
      below "RIGHT HERE"
    end

    minedText = textangle.text
    minedTextSize = minedText.size - 1

    for i in 0..minedTextSize
      if minedText[i][0].include? "WEEK 1"
        puts minedText[i][1]
        @lastweek = minedText[i][1]
      end
      if minedText[i][0].include? "WEEK 2"
        puts minedText[i][1]
        @previousweek = minedText[i][1]
      end
    end
  end  #def

end     #module
```

Comment: Can you include the contents of `ExtractHelper`?

Comment: Can u add more details please.

Comment: Added the helper code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Puts* prints to *stdout*. You're getting 0..36 in your view as helper is returning the value of its last evaluated line (a for). Try explicitly evaluating/returning something, e.g.:

```
def extract_value(filePath)
  # some initial code
  value = ''
  for i in 0..minedTextSize
    # some more code
    value = 'something'
  end
  "String concatenating some #{value}"
end
```

Comment: so... it actually print out the for statement even when i never specified it to ? that's very odd

Comment: Well it's printing a text representation of the Range you're using in the _for_. Try 

`for i in 0..36; end`

in irb. Even if _for_ is empty it returns you the original range. 
Explicitly returning some value in your helper (e.g. see my edited answer) might help.

Answer (score 0):

You have mismatching quotes in your `IO.copy_stream` that enclose `/home/ec2user/my_project/pdfFiles/Demo.pdf`. You also have an opening paren with no closing paren in the same method.

Comment: my bad . let me fix that. but that's not the issue.